# Extracting specific geometry point from MultiPoint geometry using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I am working with multipoint geometries in postgis and would like to extract the geometry point associated with the greatest y value of the multipoint geometry. How may I accomplish such a task?

For example, if my multipoint geometry is defined as follows:

`'MULTIPOINT(2 5, 3 1, 4 0)'`

Then how may I gather the geometry point associated with the greatest y-value?

The following query will tell me that the greatest y-value is 5:

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(MP), ST_YMAX(MP) FROM 
(SELECT ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(2 5, 3 0.9, 4 1.2)') as MP) as foo;
```

However, I would like to create a query that returns `'POINT(2 5)'` rather than the YMAX value of 5.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: use [`ST_Dump`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html), which will break your `MULTIPOINT` into its constituent parts.  Then sort descending by [`ST_Y(geom)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) and get the first row.

Here's a query that works on my PostGIS:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
FROM ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(2 5, 3 1, 4 0)'))
ORDER BY ST_Y(geom) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: and "Order By ST_Y(geom) ASC" to get the last point